# Loop through array of object and get values

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops, object

I have below object and i need counts from the `byPerson` array inside the object. Basically, i want to check the `count` in each `byPerson` array elements and get those properties as an array.

for e.g.

var Closed = [16, 0, 1, 43] // here 1st `count` object has 16 as closed, 2nd `count` object has no closed property (so we set it to 0), 3rd one has value 1 and 4th one has value 43

Similarly
var Verify = [0, 5, 0, 1]

How can i achieve this calculation and stored the results in `Closed` and `Verify` variables as shown above.

```
{
  "byPerson": [
    {
      "personId": "1514903899",
      "firstName": "Yatish",
      "lastName": "Patel",
      "count": {
        "Closed": 16,
      }
    },
    {
      "personId": "1559363884",
      "firstName": "Samuel",
      "lastName": "Chacko",
      "count": {
        "Verify": 5
      }
    },
    {
      "personId": "297895805",
      "firstName": "Tim",
      "lastName": "Altman",
      "count": {
        "Closed": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "personId": "others",
      "firstName": "Others",
      "lastName": "",
      "count": {
        "Closed": 43,
        "Verify": 1
      }
    }
  ],
  "resultDateTime": "2021-04-23T12:14:33.901"
}
```

I tried this way

````
const closedValues= releaseData.byPerson.map(element => element.count["Closed"] === undefined ? 0: element.count["Closed"]);
const verifyValues= releaseData.byPerson.map(element => element.count["Verify"] === undefined ? 0: element.count["Verify"]);
    ```

But i guess it is not the optimal solution where i have to calculate for each one seperately.
````

Comment: If you are using ES6 and you object is called "jsonData" : 

    const byPerson = jsonData.byPerson;

    const Closed = []; 
        const Verify = [];
        for(let i=0; i<byPerson.length;++i) {
             Closed.push( (byPerson[i].count?.Closed) ? +byPerson[i].count.Closed : 0 );
             Verify.push( (byPerson[i].count?.Verify) ? +byPerson[i].count.Verify: 0 );
        }
        
        console.log(Closed, Verify);

Comment: @Zak- added my code which i tried. not the optimal way.

Comment: @ArenTrot --  Since the question is closed (I voted to re-open) .. I created a Fiddle for you [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/ywd2z9m3/1/)  If that is what you're looking for .. I'll answer the question (with explanation)  once re-opened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to count this in one go:

```js
const data = {
  "byPerson": [{
      "personId": "1514903899",
      "firstName": "Yatish",
      "lastName": "Patel",
      "count": {
        "Closed": 16,
      }
    },
    {
      "personId": "1559363884",
      "firstName": "Samuel",
      "lastName": "Chacko",
      "count": {
        "Verify": 5
      }
    },
    {
      "personId": "297895805",
      "firstName": "Tim",
      "lastName": "Altman",
      "count": {
        "Closed": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "personId": "others",
      "firstName": "Others",
      "lastName": "",
      "count": {
        "Closed": 43,
        "Verify": 1
      }
    }
  ],
  "resultDateTime": "2021-04-23T12:14:33.901"
}

const result = data.byPerson.reduce((result, {
  count
}) => {
  result.closed.push(count.Closed || 0);
  result.verify.push(count.Verify || 0);
  return result;
}, {
  closed: [],
  verify: []
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is much better than my way.